# flex 4: does remove element also destroys the element?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I dynamically add and remove elements form VGroups. When I create an element and then append it to a VGroup and then remove it from that VGroup, does it destroy the element completely? if not, how can I destroy the element so it won't take space in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Object is sent to the garbage collector as long as there are no references to this object. which means two things:

1. all container elements that include this object should remove the element (Group,Box,Container,...)
2. all event listeners should be removed.